# ¿Cómo puedo pasar este código de estructura repetitiva FOR a la estructura WHILE en JavaScript usando jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bucle-for, botón, while

¡Hola! No sé cómo se representaría el código de abajo a una estructura repetitiva *while*. Con la estructura *for* me funciona lo más bien. El objetivo sería imprimir los enteros del -100 al 10.

```
for(i = -100; i <= 10; i++){
    console.log(`${i} <br>`);
}
```

No logro hacer que funcione con el código siguiente aunque con lo de arriba funciona. ¿Qué estaría mal?

```
let number = -100;

while(number >= 10){
    $("#pResultado").append(`${number} <br>`);
    number++;
}
```

Comment: Solo tienes mal el símbolo de comparación. En el while debe ser <= y con eso queda

Comment: Ah, ya veo. ¡Muchas gracias y perdón por la pregunta!